# How to add an overlay to a UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I have a `UITabBarController` which i want to add on top an overlay containing a registration form.
I've seen several places that the way to go is to use this command:

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:registrationView];`

But How can I create registrationView from the storyboard and be able to access it from the `UITabBarController`?

Note: My registrationView should hide the tabs so i can't put it in one tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this will solve you issue

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

 ViewController *RegistrationView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
 [tabBarController presentModalViewController:RegistrationView animated:YES];

 [tabBarController.selectedViewController viewDidAppear:true];
```

do this in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` function

Comment: I'm getting a `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:` Can I put my "ViewController" in the storyboard and give it identifier="ViewController" ?