# Add Loading view over tabbar

Tags: iphone

I want to add a loading view over the tab bar application, that when user updates it comes to the top of the screen. I added the view on window but it's not taking orientation. Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  Struggling with the problem I got some stuff 
[How to add an overlay to a UITabbarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368986/how-to-add-an-overlay-to-a-uitabbarcontroller)
which is helpful and it work for me little bit ..

```
-(void)lodingView
{
    ProcessView *LoadView = [[ProcessView alloc] init];
    [tabbarcontroller presentModalViewController:LoadView animated:YES];
    [tabbarcontroller.selectedViewController viewDidAppear:true];
}
```

We can remove the load view by this method.

```
-(void)removelodingView
{
    [tabbarcontroller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```